# Recursive Maze Algorithm (Rotating Pieces Within Maze)

Tags: algorithm, recursion, maze

The purpose of my program is to recursively solve a maze with recursion. However, my maze is an N*N grid such that each square has a directional attribute:

NS,EW,NE,NW,SE,SW and X(blocked square)

Each of these pieces can be rotated 90* clockwise.

If I was writing a recursive solution to a tradition maze I would:

```
if (x,y outside maze) return false
if (x,y is goal) return true
if (x,y not open) return false
mark x,y as part of solution path
if (FIND-PATH(North of x,y) == true) return true
if (FIND-PATH(East of x,y) == true) return true
if (FIND-PATH(South of x,y) == true) return true
if (FIND-PATH(West of x,y) == true) return true
unmark x,y as part of solution path
return false
```

Unfortunately, I'm struggling with the rotation piece. My program structure is a 2D array filled with square objects which hold their current directional value with a function to rotate. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please give an example of such a grid, and the solution the program should produce.

Comment: why are there 6 directions, instead of 4 or 8?  What do they mean?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite confusing. It's impossible to tell what you mean by the directions a cell can have and the rules for rotating them.

Having said that, all recursive backtracking algorithms take a fairly similar form:

```
solveFrom(current: State)
    if current is complete
        add current to solution set
    else
        for each possible step from state
            solveFrom(state with step added)
```

The `state with step added` often involves adding the step, calling the function recursively then removing it again.

If you only want the first solution (rather than all potential solutions) then the function can return a boolean value as yours does.

In your case I suspect your problem is that the possible steps include both moving to a new cell and rotating cells. At the moment you are only trying steps that involve moves. You need to try all possible combinations of those steps for the algorithm to work.

Answer (score 0):

The recursive algorithm is depth-first, which is inefficient and produces arbitrary solutions (the path using the greatest number of North movements in your case).

A much more appropriate approach is breadth-first, which will easily produce the shortest path, and with a lot less useless iterations.

That being said, adding the possibility to rotate cells means each cell has potentially 4 states (rotated 0, 90, 180 and 270°), though the (NS, EW) group has only 2 distinct states.
For some reason the possible cells do not include a 4 ways crossing, which would actually be unchanged by rotation, but in a more general case that could happen.

So instead of just (x,y) you need to remember (x,y,r) where r is the rotation state of a visited cell.

Now when you choose the next cell, you will need to enumerate all its possible orientations (4 for the NE,ES,SW,WN group and 2 for the NS,EW group), then check if a path exists for each, and if it does, maintain your (x,y,r) path information as you did before with just (x,y).

As for breadth-first algorithm, though it is a bit off-topic, it is basically as follows:

A "candidate move" is a move that potentially leads to a solution. It contains a a cell position and orientation, plus a reference to the previous move (in order to produce the final result).
YOu also need a state variable to keep track of the moves that have already been tried.
It can be viewed as an array of booleans, i.e. `visited[x,y,r]`, though you can implement it more efficiently with associative memory or hash tables if you are unfortunate enough to use <del>primitive</del> super-efficient languages like C++...
You define a list of candidate moves and try them sequentially like so:

```
E = entry cell
candidates := singleton list containing (E.x, E.y, 0° rotation, no parent)
while candidates is not empty
    C := get first element of candidates
    if (C.x, C.Y) is the exit
        // reconstruct solution path
        path := empty list
        do forever
           path.add (C)
           if C.parent == no parent
               return path
           C := C.parent
    if C has not already been visited
        mark C already visited
        for each neighbour N of C // the 4 cells around (C.x, C.y)
            for each rotation R of N // 0 for X, 2 for NS,EW, 4 for NE,ES,SW,WN
                if there is a path from C to R
                    add (N.x, N.y, R, C) to candidates
return failure
```

The algorithm will examine all paths stemming from the entry point in parallel until it reaches the exit, encounters an already visited cell (in the same rotation state) or runs out of virgin cells to examine (in which case the minotaur has won).

To reconstruct the solution, you follow the exit move predecessors until the very first move (which has no parent).